# Can I add a entitlements.plist to jailbreak tweaks?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'd like to restrict how much access to resources jailbreak tweaks receive. Things like network/keychain/location access... Is it possible to manually add a entitlements plist per tweak?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak is a dylib - it will be loaded in a process. That process may have entitlements and those entitlements will be used for the tweak. That's it. Tweak doesn't have it's own entitlements.

As for your question. Because of what I said before you can't restrict just a tweak - your restrictions will be applied to the whole process that is being tweaked. You can't do anything about that. That's how tweaks work - they are dylibs dynamically loaded into process address space. After that the tweak becomes a part of the process. So any restrictions will be applied to the whole process which includes the tweak, application code and any other dylib/framework application is linked to.

So if you want to develop an application which will help a user put restrictions on tweaks, I don't think you can do such a thing. What you can do is to analyze which application are being tweaked, what entitlements does they have, what frameworks and dylibs are used by a tweak (mainly the private ones). And from that user can either enable or disable that tweak. You can even analyze import section and string literals of the tweak to determine exactly which APIs does it use.

**Update**

> Could you explain to me how a native process communicates with a
>   tweak, before being loaded within the process space?

It doesn't. Before injecting tweak is a separate dylib that is not linked to any binary. CydiaSubstrate does all the injecting. The main part of the CydiaSubstrate is a special loader dylib. It's linked dynamically to `launchd` process on device start, to the process which is the first process in the iOS that starts all other processes. When a new process is spawned CydiaSubstrate loader dylib checks all tweak filters to see which ones it needs to inject into the process and injects them. After that tweak is loaded into process address space (becomes a part of the process) and tweak's constructor is called where usually all the hooks are being setup.

> Could you explain to me as to how this is accomplished?

Suppose you have an array of objc class names, C/C++ functions, frameworks and dylibs as strings usage of which you would like to detect. There's easy solution. You can open tweak's file and just search through it for any matches. As tweaks are usually not very large it shouldn't take much time. And there's more difficult solution. Use dyld or any other API to parse mach-o sections to find imported symbols and string literals and then search through them for any matches.

Comment: Thanks, please read my reply bellow I reached the character limit (:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question from a user side, but if you are making a tweak, you can add `XXX_CODESIGN_FLAGS = -Sentitlements.xml` to your Makefile to add the entitlements described in `entitlements.xml`.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to implement a script that updates a set of pre-made entitlements, either; automatically (when a new tweak is installed) or manually say through terminal; by selecting packages and patching the Makefile to include 'xx said' regulations.